# What component should be used to display a large amount of text using codenameone?

Tags: codenameone

Currently I'm using a textarea to display some terms and conditions on custom hardware (non-mobile device). This unfortunately takes something like 30-40 seconds for the screen to change, and I am assuming this is due to stringwidth calls, though I may be wrong.

Is there a way to significantly cut down the time needed to transition to this new form page with the terms and conditions, whether it be a different component used or some trick I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

We've had this problem in the past with slower devices which is why we added a lot of optimizations for the string width behavior. If you are using your own port make sure you cache `stringWidth` results in the implementation code.

Other than that make sure the columns value for the text area is large enough and that the font is consistent between selected/unselected states.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the columns value being large enough? I have not set the column value, so I assume it defaults to 1, and that I would only want 1 column when displaying a single block of text.

Comment: You can try using `setColumns(text.getLength())` columns are used to determine the preferred size of the text component as layout happens before we actually render the component and reflow isn't supported

Comment: For something like this, the BrowserComponent might be appropriate.  It allows full HTML, and it embeds a native web view which should be very fast.